# Filtrar un ListView en un CursorAdapter Android

Tags: android, listview

Hola amigos queria ver si me pueden ayudar, estoy con el siguiente inconveniente.
Tengo en un fragment un listview al cual cargo la informacion por un Cursor Adapter.
Ahora lo que quiero es poder hacer un filtro de esa lista.

En el fragment en el metodo `onCreateOptionsMenu` tengo lo siguiente

```
public class ArticulosFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PRECIO_ID = "precioId";
private OperacionesBaseDatos mOpebase;
private ListView mArticulosList;
private ArticulosCursorAdapter mArticulosAdapter;
private String mPrecioId;

public ArticulosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static ArticulosFragment newInstance(String precioId) {
    ArticulosFragment fragment = new ArticulosFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PRECIO_ID, precioId);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //obtenemos el codigo del precio seleccionado para los items
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mPrecioId = getArguments().getString(ARG_PRECIO_ID);
        if (mPrecioId==null) {
            mPrecioId=getResources().getString(R.string.precio_default);
        }
    }
    //habilitamos el toolbar
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulos, container, false);

    //referencias UI
    mArticulosList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.articulos_list);
    mArticulosAdapter = new ArticulosCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    mArticulosList.setAdapter(mArticulosAdapter);

    // Eventos
    mArticulosList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) mArticulosAdapter.getItem(i);
            String currentItemId = currentItem.getString(currentItem.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.ID));
            String currentItemCod = currentItem.getString(currentItem.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.CODIGO));
            Float currentPrecio = currentItem.getFloat(currentItem.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.PRECIO));
            ShowCantidadItems(currentItemId,currentItemCod,currentPrecio);
        }
    });

    LoadArticulos();
    return root;
}



//
//Metodo para revisar el texto del filtro
//

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar_articulos,menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mnu_articulo_buscar);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Buscar Articulo");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            query=query.toUpperCase();
            //mArticulosAdapter.getFilterQueryProvider

            mArticulosAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                    return mOpebase.ObtenerInstancia(getActivity()).BuscarProductosPorDescripcion(mPrecioId,"LAVA");
                }
            });
            Cursor xx = mOpebase.ObtenerInstancia(getActivity()).ObtenerProductosPorPrecio(mPrecioId);
            //mArticulosAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            mArticulosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                AplicarFiltro(newText);
                mArticulosList.setFilterText(newText);
            }
            //searchView.setQuery("", false);
            //searchView.setIconified(true);
            return false;
        }



    });


    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}

private void AplicarFiltro(String newText) {
    ArticulosCursorAdapter adapter = (ArticulosCursorAdapter) mArticulosList.getAdapter();
    //adapter.filter(newText);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PedidosCrearFragment.REQUEST_UPDATE_DELETE_PEDIDO) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String id=data.getStringExtra("idArticulo");
            String cod=data.getStringExtra("codiArticulo");
            String des=data.getStringExtra("descArticulo");
            Integer cant=data.getIntExtra("canIngresada",0);
            Float pre=data.getFloatExtra("precioArticulo",0);
            Integer desc=data.getIntExtra("porDescuento",0);

            Intent intentArt = new Intent();
            intentArt.putExtra("idArticulo",id);
            intentArt.putExtra("codiArticulo",cod);
            intentArt.putExtra("descArticulo",des);
            intentArt.putExtra("canIngresada",cant);
            intentArt.putExtra("precioArticulo",pre);
            intentArt.putExtra("porDescuento",desc);
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intentArt);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
}


private void  LoadArticulos(){
    new ArticulosLoadTask().execute();
}

private class ArticulosLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return mOpebase.ObtenerInstancia(getActivity()).ObtenerProductosPorPrecio(mPrecioId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mArticulosAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        } else {
            // Mostrar empty state
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No hay articulos en la lista de precio seleccionada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void ShowCantidadItems(String itemId,String itemCod,Float precio) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticuloAgregarCantidadActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ArticulosActivity.EXTRA_ARTICULO_ID, itemId);
    intent.putExtra(ArticulosActivity.EXTRA_ARTICULO_COD, itemCod);
    intent.putExtra(ArticulosActivity.EXTRA_ARTICULO_CANTIDAD, 0);
    intent.putExtra(ArticulosActivity.EXTRA_PRECIO, precio);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PedidosCrearFragment.REQUEST_UPDATE_DELETE_PEDIDO);
}
```

}

En el `onQueryTextSubmit`, tengo el texto que digita el usuario dentro de la variable query, pero no se como aplicar el filtro aqui.

Mi cursor adapter es el siguiente

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import saga.com.ec.sagamovil.R;
import saga.com.ec.sagamovil.sqlite.ContratoPedidos;

/**
 * Created by fsigu on 23/1/2017.
 */

public class ArticulosCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {

public ArticulosCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_articulo,parent,false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //referencias UI
    TextView articuloText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_articulo);
    TextView cantidadText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cantidad_articulo);
    TextView precioText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_precio_articulo);

    //get valores
    String codigo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.CODIGO));
    String articulo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.NOMBRE));
    String existencia=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.SALDO));
    String precio=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContratoPedidos.Productos.PRECIO));

    //setup
    articuloText.setText(articulo);
    cantidadText.setText(existencia);
    precioText.setText(precio);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            List<String> arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < mDatabaseOfNames.size(); i++){
                String dataNames = mDatabaseOfNames.get(i);
                if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                    FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                }
            }

            results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
            results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
            Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

            return results;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
}
```

No se si me pueden ayudar ya que he intentado de varias formas y no se como deberia aplicar el filtro.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que necesitas es implementar la interface **Filterable** en tu adapter y sus métodos, el que debes tomar muy en cuenta es el getFilter, ya que en el trabajaras la CharSecuences que filtraras y el array a filtrar:

```
public class ArticulosCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable{
    ...

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < mDatabaseOfNames.size(); i++) {
                    String dataNames = mDatabaseOfNames.get(i);
                    if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                        FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                    }
                }

                results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Y en la clase que implementas el Adapter haces lo mismo que ya tienes:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
     ...
     mArticulosAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Estimado una consulta, que tipo de variable es el mDatabaseOfNames?      Y por otro lado donde le indico por que columna debe filtrar? en el mArticulosAdapter.getFilter().filter(query); el query deberia ser algo asi? nombreColumna='FIltro de busqueda?'

Comment: Es el ArrayList<String> antes de filtrar.

Comment: Estimado Rostan no se donde tomar este valor si no lo tengo declarado porfa si me puedes ayudar, voy a postear  todo mi codigo

Comment: Por error lo monte sobre mi respuesta, edita tu pregunta y pon todo el codigo. Saludos

Comment: listo edite la pregunta y puse el codigo completo del fragment y adaptador gracias

Comment: Estimado Rostan no se si estoy mal pero yo no tengo en la clase ArticulosCursorAdapter el ArrayList antes de filtrar, lo tengo en cursor en e fragment